# ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED elastic beanstalk ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my back end Ruby on Rails code to an Elastic Beanstalk environment on AWS. I can access my MySQL database via the command line, so I know that the database has been properly deployed. When I try to access the back end via the front end from the Elastic Beanstalk URL, I am getting this error: ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED . Does this have to do with inbound traffic on the security groups? I do not have a load balancer because I only want/need a single instance. While I want secure transmission of data, I do not want or need an SSL certificate. I am not sure why I am getting this error or what it means.